# VueJS int Props changing value on prefix with 0

Tags: properties, integer, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to pass through an int value as a prop.

So if I call:

```
<job-cards-create :jobno="1203"></job-cards-create>
```

I get:

[image: answer is fine]

But if I add even one '0' infront:

```
<job-cards-create :jobno="01203"></job-cards-create>
```

It gives:

[image: answer is way off]

What is going on? Am I missing something?

Comment: It's irrelevant to Vue I suppose. It's native JS behavior: type into console parseInt(01203, 10) -> result will be 643. Why - I don't know, looking to see someone answering here.

Comment: Are you hard coding the value like in the question or does it come from somewhere?

Comment: @wostex That behavior is due to the fact that parseInt expects a string: `parseInt('01203', 10) -> 1203`. Your value is getting coerced into a string as an octal value: `01203.toString() -> "643"`

Comment: @AJGregory, why parseInt('01203', 8) = 419? Shouldn't it be 643 also?

Comment: @wostex When I try `parseInt("01203", 8)` I do get 643. Maybe you tried `parseInt(01203, 8)` which is the same as `parseInt("643", 8)` and returns 419.

Comment: @AJGregory thanks mate.

Comment: @BertEvans I am writing a project, and realized this when using integers with prefixes of 0, when job numbers had no 0, all was good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your number `01203` is being interpreted as an octal number due to the leading zero. Check out these examples:

`01203 === 643 // true`

`01203.toString() // "643"`

[Here is some documentation on octals in JS](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/octalsan.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need it to be a number? It doesn't look like you're going to be performing any calculations on it. Just knock off the `v-bind` and use a string literal instead:

```
<job-cards-create jobno="01203"></job-cards-create>
```